(Windows) Setting environment variables with spaces in text
I am trying to install llama-cpp-python on Windows 11. I have installed and set up the CMAKE_ARGS environment variable to point to the MinGW gcc.exe and g++.exe to compile C and C++, but am struggling to set up the -G parameter, the generator because it quotes MinGW Makefiles as an option, but when I input this after the generator parameter, the variable text is separated by the space in the middle. I'd appreciate the help!
Here is the portion of the error message relevant to this issue:
 Building wheel for llama-cpp-python (pyproject.toml) ... error
  error: subprocess-exited-with-error

  × Building wheel for llama-cpp-python (pyproject.toml) did not run successfully.
  │ exit code: 1
  ╰─> [86 lines of output]
      *** scikit-build-core 0.9.2 using CMake 3.29.1 (wheel)
      *** Configuring CMake...
      2024-04-26 23:46:20,586 - scikit_build_core - WARNING - Can't find a Python library, got libdir=None, ldlibrary=None, multiarch=None, masd=None
      CMake Error: Could not create named generator "MinGW

      Generators
        Visual Studio 17 2022        = Generates Visual Studio 2022 project files.
                                       Use -A option to specify architecture.
        Visual Studio 16 2019        = Generates Visual Studio 2019 project files.
                                       Use -A option to specify architecture.
        Visual Studio 15 2017 [arch] = Generates Visual Studio 2017 project files.
                                       Optional [arch] can be "Win64" or "ARM".
        Visual Studio 14 2015 [arch] = Generates Visual Studio 2015 project files.
                                       Optional [arch] can be "Win64" or "ARM".
        Visual Studio 12 2013 [arch] = Deprecated.  Generates Visual Studio 2013
                                       project files.  Optional [arch] can be
                                       "Win64" or "ARM".
        Visual Studio 9 2008 [arch]  = Deprecated.  Generates Visual Studio 2008
                                       project files.  Optional [arch] can be
                                       "Win64" or "IA64".
        Borland Makefiles            = Generates Borland makefiles.
      * NMake Makefiles              = Generates NMake makefiles.
        NMake Makefiles JOM          = Generates JOM makefiles.
        MSYS Makefiles               = Generates MSYS makefiles.
        MinGW Makefiles              = Generates a make file for use with
                                       mingw32-make.
        Green Hills MULTI            = Generates Green Hills MULTI files
                                       (experimental, work-in-progress).
        Unix Makefiles               = Generates standard UNIX makefiles.
        Ninja                        = Generates build.ninja files.
        Ninja Multi-Config           = Generates build-<Config>.ninja files.
        Watcom WMake                 = Generates Watcom WMake makefiles.
        CodeBlocks - MinGW Makefiles = Generates CodeBlocks project files
                                       (deprecated).
        CodeBlocks - NMake Makefiles = Generates CodeBlocks project files
                                       (deprecated).
        CodeBlocks - NMake Makefiles JOM
                                     = Generates CodeBlocks project files
                                       (deprecated).
        CodeBlocks - Ninja           = Generates CodeBlocks project files
                                       (deprecated).
        CodeBlocks - Unix Makefiles  = Generates CodeBlocks project files
                                       (deprecated).
        CodeLite - MinGW Makefiles   = Generates CodeLite project files
                                       (deprecated).
        CodeLite - NMake Makefiles   = Generates CodeLite project files
                                       (deprecated).
        CodeLite - Ninja             = Generates CodeLite project files
                                       (deprecated).
        CodeLite - Unix Makefiles    = Generates CodeLite project files
                                       (deprecated).
        Eclipse CDT4 - NMake Makefiles
                                     = Generates Eclipse CDT 4.0 project files
                                       (deprecated).
        Eclipse CDT4 - MinGW Makefiles
                                     = Generates Eclipse CDT 4.0 project files
                                       (deprecated).
        Eclipse CDT4 - Ninja         = Generates Eclipse CDT 4.0 project files
                                       (deprecated).
        Eclipse CDT4 - Unix Makefiles= Generates Eclipse CDT 4.0 project files
                                       (deprecated).
        Kate - MinGW Makefiles       = Generates Kate project files (deprecated).
        Kate - NMake Makefiles       = Generates Kate project files (deprecated).
        Kate - Ninja                 = Generates Kate project files (deprecated).
        Kate - Ninja Multi-Config    = Generates Kate project files (deprecated).
        Kate - Unix Makefiles        = Generates Kate project files (deprecated).
        Sublime Text 2 - MinGW Makefiles
                                     = Generates Sublime Text 2 project files
                                       (deprecated).
        Sublime Text 2 - NMake Makefiles
                                     = Generates Sublime Text 2 project files
                                       (deprecated).
        Sublime Text 2 - Ninja       = Generates Sublime Text 2 project files
                                       (deprecated).
        Sublime Text 2 - Unix Makefiles
                                     = Generates Sublime Text 2 project files
                                       (deprecated).

      CMake Warning:
        Ignoring extra path from command line:

         "Makefiles""



      *** CMake configuration failed
      [end of output]

I have tried -G MinGW Makefiles, -G 'MinGW Makefiles, -G "MinGW Makefiles" and -G MinGW\ Makefiles but none of these common ways to include spaces in the environment variable definition are working.

The correct would be to use double quotes: -G "MinGW Makefiles".
But the Ninja build tool is a lot faster, so you could use -G Ninja if you have ninja in your path.
